# Prove if wronskian is zero then solutions of ODE are linearly dependant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have $$y'' + P(x)y' + Q(x)y = 0 $$

and let the solutions be $y_1, y_2$ in $[a,b]$. The wronskian is $y_1 y_2' - y_2 y_1'$, which is identically zero. Now lets consider 3 cases:

1. If $y_1$ is identically zero, then so is $W(x)$ and so $y_1 = 0(y_2)$ so they are linearly dependant.
2. If $y_1$ is never zero in $[a,b]$ then $\frac{W(x)}{y_1^2} = \left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)' = 0$ or $y_2 = c y_1$ so they are L.D.
3. What if $y_1$ is zero only on some points in $[a,b]$ and say $y_1'$ is also zero at those points, how do we show $y_2, y_2'$ is also zero at those points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list $\{y_1, y_2 \} $ were independent, then we can find nontrivial $(c_1, c_2)$ so that

$$ c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2 = 0$$

differentiation gives

$$ c_1 y_1' + c_2 y_2' = 0 $$

and so the system

$$ \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y_1' & y_2' \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} = 0 $$

has a nontrivial solution which means that $det $ of the coefficient matrix, that is $y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2$ cannot be zero.